# El bot discord no se activa

Tags: python, discord.py

Pues el problema que tengo es que hice un bot con python, que saluda a los nuevos miembros, pero no sé por qué el bot no se activa: aparece desconectado. Hice todo como corresponde (al menos eso creo). Aquí la versión de python es 3.9.

El código:

```
import discord

token = "token" #por cosas de privacidad no lo puedo publicar

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
        await member.send(f"Bienvenido programador {member.name}")
        client.run(token)
```

Comment: El `client.run(token)` lo tienes que poner fuera del evento (elimina la indentación de esa línea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estas salteando varios comandos

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="Hey there, I'm bot!") # description es la descripcion que te aparecera cuando veas el perfil del bot

token = "" # your token

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready!")
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Bot", url="http://")) 
# puedes cambiar el estado, este es el que yo uso para los mios
# discord.Streaming() es para poner links a un canal de twitch o youtube para streamig. Pon el link en *url*

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server.')
    channel = client.get_channel(123445667890) # aca pon el id del canal de bienvenida
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome", description="Welcome to the server, " + member, color=999)
    embed.set_footer(text="Your footer") # esta funcion se puede saltear
    await channel.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(token)
```

espero que te sea de ayuda!

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, aunque tengo todavia un problema es que repite el mensaje

Comment: como? se envia dos veces?

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias ya solucione el problema un error tonto

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, se aprecia